# How to pass the value for the dropdown from using each method and input decorator in angular 14

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular8, angular14

I'm trying to set the values for the dropdown using foreach method, but it's not working properly. It is loading 5 times for each dropdown. I want to show the proper value for the dropdown. Example: For Car dropdown I want to show only the value of Car from the array. Same like for others. How to do it?

main.component.html:

```
<div
  class="custom-select"
  style="width:400px;"
  *ngFor="let v of vehicle; index as i"
  >
  <p>{{ v }}</p>
  <app-vehicle [data]="travals"></app-vehicle>
</div>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yxfoyl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fmain.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This's what you need?

**vehicle.component.html**

```
<select>
  <option
    *ngFor="let vehicleType of data; index as i"
    value="{{ vehicleType }}"
    label="{{ vehicleType }}"
  ></option>
</select>
```

**main.component.html**

```
<div
  class="custom-select"
  style="width:400px;"
  *ngFor="let v of vehicle; index as i"
>
  <p>{{ v }}</p>
  <app-vehicle [data]="travals[v]"></app-vehicle>
</div>
```